# Change missing areas value(0) to other in Google Dynamic World Landcover Yearly Mode Mosaic to not mix with water class (also 0)

Tags: masking, land-cover, nodata, google-earth-engine

When I create a yearly mode mosaic using Google Dynamic World Landcover Data, the areas with missing landcover values especially in high Himalayan regions(perhaps due to the 35% cloud threshold) are assigned a value of zero. But zero is also assigned to water class in the label band. Therefore, these missing areas add up in the water category on export. I have tried using

```
var dwComposite = classification.reduce(ee.Reducer.mode()).unmask(-999)
```

and also used below to reclassify the water category:

```
dwComposite = ee.Image(1)
      .where(dwComposite.eq(0), 1)
      .where(dwComposite.eq(1), 2)
      .where(dwComposite.eq(2), 3)
      .where(dwComposite.eq(3), 4)
      .where(dwComposite.eq(4), 5)
      .where(dwComposite.eq(5), 6)
      .where(dwComposite.eq(6), 7)
      .where(dwComposite.eq(7), 8)
      .where(dwComposite.eq(8), 9)
```

Still, the water and missing areas are in the same category on export.
[image: Water body in missing areas]

Comment: Could you attach the link to your code?

Comment: https://code.earthengine.google.com/1b933c97a00fc26752a897596119f2fe

Answer (score 2):

You were almost there, but you have to do it in a different order. In the first place you have to reclassify the collection and then you have to get the mode and mask.

In my example, I reclassify by a function which creates a new band named label2. If you visualize it with your legend, you will see how empty values are now black while water values are blue.

```
var Clipfile = geometry
var startDate = '2020-01-01';
var endDate = '2020-12-30';

/////////////// S2 imagery ////////////////////////////
var s2 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_HARMONIZED')
             .filterDate(startDate, endDate)
             .filterBounds(Clipfile)
             .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 35));

var s2Image = s2.median().clip(Clipfile)

////////////////// Dynamic World ////////////////////////
var dw = ee.ImageCollection('GOOGLE/DYNAMICWORLD/V1')
             .filterDate(startDate, endDate)
             .filterBounds(Clipfile);

// Select label layer
var classification = dw.select('label');

// Reclassify function
var reclas = function(image) { 
  var label = image.select("label");
  var label2 =label
        .where(label.eq(0), 1)
      .where(label.eq(1), 2)
      .where(label.eq(2), 3)
      .where(label.eq(3), 4)
      .where(label.eq(4), 5)
      .where(label.eq(5), 6)
      .where(label.eq(6), 7)
      .where(label.eq(7), 8)
      .where(label.eq(8), 9)
  return image.addBands(label2.rename('label2'));
};

// Let's reclassify
var r_classification = classification.map(reclas);

// Now we can mask
var dwComposite = r_classification.reduce(ee.Reducer.mode()).unmask(-999)



////////////////////// Mapping and Visualiztion /////////////////////////
var s2VisParams = {bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'], min: 0, max: 3000};
var dwVisParams = {bands:'label2_mode', // Don't forget to choose the right band!
  min: 0,
  max: 8,
  palette: ['#000000', '#419BDF', '#397D49', '#88B053', '#7A87C6',
    '#E49635', '#DFC35A', '#C4281B', '#A59B8F', '#B39FE1']
}; 


Map.centerObject(Clipfile, 11);
Map.addLayer(s2Image, s2VisParams, 'Sentinel-2 Image');
Map.addLayer(dwComposite.clip(Clipfile), dwVisParams, 'Google Composite')
```